# SAS hash join in form LIKE or =:

Tags: hash, sas, datastep

is it possible to do a SAS hash lookup on a partial substring?

So the hash table key will contain:  'LongString' but my target table key has: 'LongStr'

(the target table key string length may vary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can but it's not pretty and you may not get the performance benefits you're looking for.  Also, depending on the length of your strings and the size of your table you may not be able to fit all the hashtable elements into memory.

The trick is to first generate all of the possible substrings and then to use the 'multidata' option on the hashtable.

Create a dataset containing words we want to match against:

```
data keys;
  length key  $10 value $1;
  input key;
  cards;
LongString
LongOther
;
run;
```

Generate all possible substrings:

```
data abbreviations;
  length abbrev $10;
  set keys;
  do cnt=1 to length(key);
    abbrev = substr(key,1,cnt);
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Create a dataset containing terms we want to search for:

```
data match_attempts;
  length abbrev  $10;
  input abbrev ;
  cards;
L
Long
LongO
LongSt
LongOther
;
run;
```

Perform the lookup:

```
data match;
  length abbrev key $10;

  set match_attempts;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash h1(dataset:'abbreviations', multidata: 'y');
    h1.defineKey('abbrev');
    h1.defineData('abbrev', 'key');
    h1.defineDone();

    call missing(abbrev, key);
  end;

  if h1.find() eq 0 then do;
    output;
    h1.has_next(result: r);
    do while(r ne 0);
      h1.find_next();
      output;
      h1.has_next(result: r);
    end;
  end;

  drop r;
run;
```

Output (notice how 'Long' returns 2 matches):

```
Obs abbrev    key 
=== ========= ==========
1   Long      LongString 
2   Long      LongOther 
3   LongO     LongOther 
4   LongSt    LongString 
5   LongOther LongOther
```

A few more notes.  The reason the hash table will not support something like the `like` operator is because it 'hashes' the key prior to inserting a record into the hash table.  When a lookup is performed the value to lookup is 'hashed' and then a match is performed on the hashed values.  When a value is hashed even a small change in the value will yield a completely different result.  Take the below example, hashing 2 almost identical strings yields 2 completely different values:

```
data _null_;
  length hashed_value $16;
  hashed_value = md5("String");
  put hashed_value= hex32.;
  hashed_value = md5("String1");
  put hashed_value= hex32.;
run;
```

Output:

```
hashed_value=27118326006D3829667A400AD23D5D98
hashed_value=0EAB2ADFFF8C9A250BBE72D5BEA16E29
```

For this reason, the hash table cannot use the `like` operator.

Finally, thanks to @vasja for some sample data.

Comment: Had to accept vasja's response on grounds of efficiency, however +1 for some very interesting insights into hash tables.  Am sure the two repsonses could be combined (eg using the multidata option instead of hiter)..

Comment: Actually mine will be more efficient once the table reaches a certain size.  @vasja's solution should run at O(N * M / 2) speed as for every row it must traverse the iterator until it finds or doesn't find a match.  On average it will iterate through half the dataset.  Mine has a higher initial overhead, but will find the match in O(N) time which is much faster as the number of obs increases.  If you're wondering what these times mean do some searching on 'Big O' notation.  For small datasets you're better off just using an SQL join with `like` anyway - don't overcomplicate with a hash table.

Comment: To put that into real terms. If it takes @vasjas solution 1ms to iterate through the hash then it will take on average 0.5ms to get a result for the each row.  If the large table has 10M rows and say it also takes 30 seconds for SAS to traverse 10M rows that's a total of 83min30sec.  In my solution, the time to search is the cost of applying the hash function to the search term and retrieve the result from memory - which is basically nothing.  So the total time of my solution for the same 10M rows would simply be the 30 seconds for SAS to traverse the 10M rows + setup time.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Iterator object to loop through the keys and do the matching by yourself.

```
 data keys;
length key  $10 value $1;
input key value;
cards;
LongString A
LongOther B
;
run;

proc sort data=keys;
by key;
run;


data data;
length short_key  $10;
input short_key ;
cards;
LongStr
LongSt
LongOther
LongOth
LongOt
LongO
LongSt
LongOther
;
run;

data match;
    set data;
    length key $20 outvalue value $1;
    drop key value rc;
    if _N_ = 1 then do;
       call missing(key, value);
       declare hash h1(dataset:"work.keys", ordered: 'yes');
       declare hiter iter ('h1');
       h1.defineKey('key');
       h1.defineData('key', 'value');
       h1.defineDone();
    end;
    rc = iter.first();/* reset to beginning */
    do while (rc = 0);/* loop through the long keys and find a match */
        if index(key, trim(short_key)) > 0 then do;
            outvalue = value;
            iter.last(); /* leave after match */
        end;
        rc = iter.next(); 
    end; 
run;
```